# read a file using command line argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

how can I pass a file as command line argument

```
a=np.loadtxt("graph3.txt",dtype='float')
```

now I want to pass the above file graph3.txt as command line argument as python x.py graph3.txt and put perform the above operation a=np.loadtxt("graph3.txt",dtype='float') on comman line argument

Comment: I think Google can give you much more answers and articles without awaiting for the answer on stackoverflow. It's basic question, answer in any book for newbies of Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can use libraries like argparse or docopt, but for simple tasks just look at sys.argv:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Please inform the filename")
    exit(1)

fname = sys.argv[1]
try:
    a = np.loadtxt(fname, dtype='float')
except IOError:
    print("File '%s' doesn't exist", fname)
    exit(1)

# Program continues
```

Answer (score 1):

Python command line arguments are stored in `sys` modules' list variable `argv`. So the code you are looking for is:

```
import sys
a = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], dtype='float')
```

assuming you pass the file name as the first parameter to the script as noted in your question.

Documentation here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argv` from `sys` module:

`from sys import argv
print argv`

You will get all command line arguments in a `list` where `0`th position in the list will be the name of the script itself

`[~]$ python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
['script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4']`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support lots of arguments and provide help usage for them, I think [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) and [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) do such things well.

There is an example for `optparse`:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser(version="%prog 1.0.0")
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", action="store", dest="file",
                      default="graph3.txt", type="string",
                      help="specify a file to load")
options, args = parser.parse_args()
a=np.loadtxt(options.file,dtype="float")
```

Then, you can use the script like this: `./script.py -f gragh3.txt` or `./script.py --file=gragh3.txt`.

And you can use `./script.py -h` to make the script print the usage doc.